# Instagram Embed Changing Style

Tags: html, instagram

I would like to know can I change the look of the embed link from Instagram. I'm planning to change it to how it looks in these photos.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That looks like a custom implementation using [Instagram’s API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api)